# overloaded assigment operator not called

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Thank you all for your answers. And thanks for the cppinsight and godbolt, did not know these.

I edited my question here what I want to do. Basically I have a SDK acquisition function that has an pointer float argument as input, and I want to monitor that argument in real time to know the status of the acquisition. Now i got this code to work:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class MonitoredVariable
{
public:
    MonitoredVariable() {}
   // MonitoredVariable(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

    operator T&() { return m_value; }
   //operator const T&() const { return m_value; }

    MonitoredVariable& operator = (float value)
    {
        printf("Variable modified\n");
        this->m_value = &value;
        printf("%f \n", *this->m_value);
   
        return *this;
    }

      MonitoredVariable&  operator * () {return *this;}
    
private:
    T m_value;
};

void SDKfunctionIcannotChange(float *a)
{
    *a = (float) 5.2; 
    printf("%f \n", *a); // if I comment this out, x will not update?!?!
    return;
}

int main()
{
    MonitoredVariable<float*> x;
    *x=0;
    SDKfunctionIcannotChange(x);
    printf("%f \n", *x);
    
return 1;
}
```

But strangely if I comment out that `printf` command in the `SDKfunctionIcannotChange` function, then the x value will not change. Any ideas why is this happening?

So with printf (correct):

```
Variable modified
0.000000 
5.200000 
5.200000
```

and without

```
Variable modified
0.000000 
0.000000
```

thanks..

Comment: `*m_value = value.m_value;` is undefined behavior, because you never set `m_value` to point to a `float`. To store a `float` you need a `float` somewhere, not just a pointer

Comment: `*x` is not an instance of your class. Implicit conversions usually seem like a neat idea at first, but they aren't, really. Add some printing in yours.

Comment: `float*` != `float`.

Comment: Unrelated: `void main()` is not valid C++. Make it `int main()`

Comment: ps: My first comment is partly due to me misreading the code. Nevertheless it is part of the problem, so I leave the comment, even though it is not quite correct

Comment: Question turn out to be [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) :(. Please provide actual name(s) of `SDKfunctionIcannotChange` function, so we can quote its documentation and explain why you made this over-complicated. And explain what you need to achieve.

Comment: My intend was just to present the bare minimum to keep things short and simple.

Answer (score 3):

This answers original question before extensive edit.

Basically your program is equivalent to:

```cpp
int main()
{
    float *x = nullptr;
    float y = 5;
    *x = y; // here is UB since x == nullptr
}
```

See [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/989b2d0b): problematic line looks like this `*static_cast<float *>(x.operator float *&()) = y;`. So your code do not use custom `operator=`, but conversion operator.
Basically problem is code which uses template.

I do not know what was your intent, maybe this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class MonitoredVariable
{
public:
    MonitoredVariable() {}
    MonitoredVariable(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

    operator T&() { return m_value; }
    operator const T&() const { return m_value; }

    MonitoredVariable& operator = (const T& value)
    {
        printf("Variable modified\n");
        m_value = value; // here was also a problem
        return *this;
    }

int main()
{
    MonitoredVariable<float*> x;
    float y = 5;
    x = &y;

    return;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/js5zdz

Comment: An alternative could be to make the template parameter `float` instead of `float*` which would simplify the usage. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/bn5fzh)

Comment: Yes this is another interpretation of his intent.

Answer (score 1):

The `*x` expression calls `operator*` with an argument of `x`. During the [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), a builtin `operator*` for pointers is found. Given that your class `MonitoredVariable` has a conversion operator to `T` (which is a pointer type in your case), that conversion operator is called and the returned pointer, which is null, is then dereferenced causing a crash.

What you probably wanted to write is `x = y`.

Comment: What if OP had defined a `operator*`?

Comment: @Lingo Then that operator would have been called, obviously. But then the OP would have to also implement a reference proxy to intercept the following assignment. It is not clear what is the intention of the `MonitoredVariable` class, so I can't tell if this would be the recommended solution.